# How do I return a value from an if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am very new to not only C# but programming as a whole, and I understand that this is a very basic question, but I just dont know how to return a value from an if statement. This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int couscous = RandomNumber(1);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (couscous > 1)
    {
        int remainder = couscous % 3;
        if (remainder == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(couscous / 3);
            int step2 = couscous / 3;
           // I want to return couscous / 3 to the beginning of the while statement so it repeats all the code but with step2 instead of couscous.
        }
        else if (remainder != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(couscous + 1);
        }
    }
}

static int RandomNumber(int i)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    i = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
    int input = i;
    return input;
```

Comment: Instead of `int step2 = couscous / 3;` write `couscous /= 3;` and also `i = rnd.Next(1, 1000);  int input = i;  return input;` does the same as `return rnd.Next(1, 1000);`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this and also you would learn more about [return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return).
Because a void cannot have a return.

```cs
using System;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ifReturn());
        }

        static string ifReturn()
        {
            bool good = true;
            if (good)
            {
                return "It was true";
            }
            else
            {
                return "It was false";
            }
        }
    }
}
```